# Remove line after specific character with REGEX Python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to remove specific characters with REGEX in Python and the line which comes after the character of a list.

For instance:

```
First Name:
Eric
```

I would like to remove both "First Name:" AND "Eric" but leave what comes afterwards.

Could you please help? This just deletes the first line:

```py
remove_list = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Age"]
for i in remove_list:
    rmv_regex = re.compile("(?m)^"+ i + ".*\n" +".*\n", re.IGNORECASE) # Ignore case, regex of lines that start with the keywords
```

Comment: It seems you have not pasted all the relevant code lines. Please edit the question. What does `remove_list` hold?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this question, just enable re.MULTILINE.
For instance in this text:

```
   First Name:
   Eric
   Last Name:
   Dirkson
   Age:
   34
```

Solve with this:

```
    remove_list = ["First Name", "Last Name", "Age"]
      for i in remove_list:
      rmv_regex = re.compile("(?m)^"+ i + ".*\n"+ ".*\n", re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)
      text = rmv_regex.sub('', text)
```